# Is it possible to extend Methods in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I know it is possible to do this in Java:

```
public class animal {...}
```

And then

```
public class dog extends animal {...}
```

Then you can write whatever dog methods that can access animal method.

However, I am wondering is there a way to extend methods

for example

```
public void generateAnimal() {...}
```

and then

```
public void generateDog() extends generateAnimal() {...}
```

But this is not passing the compiler.
So my question is:

Is it possible to inherit methods in Java?

Comment: What do you imagine this would do if it existed?

Comment: I don't think so. If you extend the class, you can call `super()` in the methods you override. That's the most similar thing I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
public class Animal {
   public void someAction() {
      System.out.println("from Animal class");
   }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   public void someAction() {
      super.someAction();
      System.out.println("from Dog class");
   }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Animal dog = new Dog();
      dog.someAction();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
from Animal class    
from Dog class
```

So you extend functionality of method, but better to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Note that the order of the output is incorrect: first you get `from Animal` and only then, `from Dog`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot extend a method the way you are describing but you can inherit the method and then call the method from the superclass as follows:

```
@Override
public void inheritedMethod() {
    super.inheritedMethod(); // This will call method from super class

    // Do subclass specific work here
}
```

A method is not an object by itself. Methods are meant to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It was done exactly as you showed there, without the `extends generateAnimal()` and by changing that method name to `generateAnimal()`.

This is called Overriding. And allows you to utilize the annotation `@Override`.

---

```
public class A {

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hello from A!");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override  // This method overrides A#print() 
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hello from B!");
    }

}
```

Then, calling some action like:

```
B b = new B();
b.print();
```

Will print out:

```
Hello from B!
```

---

This is more widely known as [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same class, no. However, assuming you want to run all of generateAnimal() then add your generateDog() specific code you could do this:

```
public void generateDog(){
    generateAnimal();
    ///do the rest of generateDog()
}
```

I hope that helps.